# Looping through an object

Tags: vue.js

I have an object that looks like this

```
category_1: [
    [
        id: 1,
        name: 'Product 1',
        tags: []
    ],
    [
        id: 2,
        name: 'Product 2',
        tags: []
    ]
],
category_2: [
    [
        id: 3,
        name: 'Product 3',
        tags: []
    ],
    [
        id: 4,
        name: 'Product 4',
        tags: ['blue']
    ],
    [
        id: 5,
        name: 'Product 5',
        tags: []
    ],
    [
        id: 6,
        name: 'Product 6',
        tags: ['blue']
    ]
]
```

and what I'm trying to do is grab everything in my category, for example category_2 and grab only the items that has blue in the tags.
This issue I'm having is that I get the first item and it just loops a couple of times with just that item.

Here is my code

```
getCategories(){
    Object.keys(categories).forEach(category => {
        if(category === 'category_2'){
            categories[category].forEach(c => {
                if(c.tags.includes('blue') === true){
                    this.categorydata.push(c)
                }
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all are you sure you want categories to be arrays of arrays? If you want items of categories to be objects instead of arrays than you are using the wrong notation. If you want your category to be consisted of objects and not arrays, change your code to this:

```
      category_1: [
        { id: 1, name: "Product 1", tags: [] },
        { id: 2, name: "Product 2", tags: [] },
      ],
      category_2: [
        { id: 3, name: "Product 3", tags: [] },
        { id: 4, name: "Product 4", tags: ["blue"] },
        { id: 5, name: "Product 5", tags: [] },
        { id: 6, name: "Product 6", tags: ["blue"] },
      ],
```

With that out of the way, you can do what you want using [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Your code should look like this:

```
getCategories(categoryName, wantedTag){
    return categories[categoryName].filter(item => item.tags.includes(wantedTag));
}
```